# c# and removing sensitive data and all garbage collection copies from memory

Tags: c#, string, security, stream, garbage-collection

I am attempting to protect my windows Service Project against a memory scraper.  I am attempting to store some extremely sensitive data. Lets use a Credit Card Number "1234-5678-1234-5678" for example.  there are two main C# objects I need to be able to store this data into, and remove it when I complete.

I have been able to store and remove sensitive data from a custom-class I built with help from StackOverflow examples:

```
public void DestorySensitiveData()
{
    try
    {
        unsafe
        {
            int iDataSize = m_chSensitiveData.Length;
            byte[] clear = new byte[iDataSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < clear.Length; i++)
            {
                clear[i] = 70;  //fixed ascii character
            }

            fixed (char* ptr = &m_chSensitiveData[0])
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(clear, 0, new IntPtr(ptr), iDataSize);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

by using a Char Array instead of a string I have been able to override/wipe the sensitive data in memory.  Without this class the Memory Management of .NET and Strings could and would copy this data around wherever it needed it.  Even when my class fell out of scope or I attempted to call dispose I could run a memory scrape and find my sensitive data in plain text, as easy as you are reading this paragraph.

I am looking for a practice or method for Streams.  I need to be able to move sensitive data to/from a System.Diagnostics.Process() or even a File.  Its 'ok' for the data to be in plain text while I am using it - it just cannot remain ANYWHERE in memory when I am finished using it.  This includes copies made by memory management or garbage collection.

Examples that DONT work:

- Strings/StringBuilders:  These are constantly re-newing themselves leaving fragments everywhere.
- SecureString:   Class looks great on paper, and on MSDN. however you MUST use a String to both Load and Unload this Object  (see item #1)
- ArrayLists.  really a String problem in two dimensions.

I even tried creating a seperate EXE project and doing my memory-sensitive work inside the process.  I got bit when I had to overload the input/output streams.

Streams seem to be copied all over the place.  in my application I created a single stream, loaded my sensitive data into it then completed.  I loaded my sensitive data ONCE and I found about a dozen complete copies through the raw memory after execution completed.

Has anyone come across similar issues in .NET before?  How were they solved?

Update: 1/16/15:

I have to send the Credit Card off to be processed, by software running on same machine:

```
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"<full working path>";

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"<vendor EXE>"; 
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "<args>";                    
        proc.Start();                                       
        //pTran.ProcessorData.ProcID = proc.Id;
        StreamWriter myWriter = proc.StandardInput;
        StreamReader myReader = proc.StandardOutput;
        // Send request API to Protobase

        //I need a process to send the data
        //even if I use a protected object to hold it, 
        //the 'myWriter' cannot be controlled
        **myWriter.Write(sSensitiveData);**  
        myWriter.Flush();
        myWriter.Close();
        // Read Response API
        string sResponseData = myReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(sResponseData);
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
        myReader.Close();
```

This is why I was asking about the Stream classes and destroying the memory they contain.  Unlike a Password which we store and compare as a hash, this data must be readable by our vendor.

@Greg:  I like your idea of mutual agreed encryption between my process and vendor.  I am already working on that angle.

Other than encryption of data and allowing GC to copy fragments all over the place, is there a way to scrub memory from a Stream type class?

Comment: have you thought about some strong encryption of the values and writing or using some decryption code on the target or source machine..?

Comment: Can you be more specific about why SecureString doesn't meet your need?

Comment: YES!  The reason SecureString isnt working for me is I have to send this information to a 3rd Party Vendor, then read the response. I am creating a System.Diagnostics.Process() and overloading the Input/Output to pass the data.  The only objects that can do this that I am aware of is a Stream/StreamWriter class.  I also have a File I/0 options (which will require a call for sdelete.exe) but the File I/O in C# cannot use SecureString either.

Comment: Read into a pre-allocated byte array. Then convert the value to a SecureString and wipe the byte array. At this point it cannot be read from memory. When you need to do I/O, do the reverse. Put the value from SecureString into a byte array, transmit, and wipe it again. Of course, during the transmit it is in memory and on the I/O channel so it can be read from there. Theoretically, at least.

Comment: One suggestion - when you create your `m_chSensitiveData` object be sure to pin it using `GCHandle.Alloc(m_chSensitiveData, GCHandleType.Pinned)` and store handle as member then after clearing it call `.Free()` on the handle.  This will prevent your object from being moved around if/when the heap is compacted, as moving it will leave the bits behind until overwritten. The `fixed` does this already for its scope, but you probably don't want it moved for the lifetime of the object. I'm surprised Array.Clear() isn't good enough for an Array of char (value type), however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - Thank you all for the ideas and assistance!

We could not use a SecureString, as we were sending data to a 3rd party.  Char Arrays were not possible due to the System.Process() only allowing Streams.  Then we built a c++ MiddleLayer to receive encrypted data, decrypt and transmit using a STARTUPINFO.  Our initial solution used streams for I/O and this was an 'almost perfect' solution as we were down to the c++ stream remaining in memory.

We contacted Microsoft for assistance, who suggested an almost identical solution, but using Handles/PIPES instead of streams, so you can close both ends of the pipe.

Here is the sample, dummied code.  Hope this helps someone else!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv [])
{
HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
STARTUPINFO StartInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
BOOL fResult;
HANDLE hReadPipe = NULL;
HANDLE hWritePipe = NULL;
HANDLE hSensitiveReadPipe = NULL;
HANDLE hSensitiveWritePipe = NULL;
DWORD dwDataLength = 0;
DWORD dwWritten;
DWORD dwRead;
char responseData[1024];
char *sensitiveDataChar = NULL;
char *otherStuff = NULL;
char *sensitiveDataCharB = NULL;
DWORD dwSectorsPerCluster;
DWORD dwBytesPerSector;
DWORD dwNumberOfFreeClusters;
DWORD dwTotalNumberOfClusters;
SIZE_T SizeNeeded;

__try
{

    sensitiveDataChar = "YourSensitiveData";
    int lastLoc = 0;


    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    // Create Pipe to send sensitive data
    fResult = CreatePipe(&hSensitiveReadPipe, &hSensitiveWritePipe, &sa, 0);
    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("CreatePipe failed with %d", GetLastError());
        __leave;
    }

    // Create Pipe to read back response
    fResult = CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &sa, 0);
    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("CreatePipe failed with %d", GetLastError());
        __leave;
    }

    // Initialize STARTUPINFO structure
    ZeroMemory(&StartInfo, sizeof(StartInfo));
    StartInfo.cb = sizeof(StartInfo);
    StartInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    StartInfo.hStdInput = hSensitiveReadPipe;
    StartInfo.hStdOutput = hWritePipe;
    StartInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Launch third party app
    fResult = CreateProcess(_T("c:\\temp\\ThirdParty.exe"), NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, _T("c:\\temp"), &StartInfo, &pi);
    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed with %d", GetLastError());
        __leave;
    }

    dwDataLength = strlen(sensitiveDataChar);
    // Write to third party's standard input
    fResult = WriteFile(hSensitiveWritePipe, sensitiveDataChar, dwDataLength, &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("WriteFile failed with %d", GetLastError());
        __leave;
    }
    FlushFileBuffers(hSensitiveWritePipe);
    CloseHandle(hSensitiveReadPipe);

    DWORD dwLength = 1024;
    printf("Waiting...\n");

    // Read from third party's standard out
    fResult = ReadFile(hReadPipe, responseData, dwLength, &dwRead, NULL);
    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("ReadFile failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        __leave;
    }
    responseData[dwRead] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", responseData);       
}
__finally
{
    // Clean up
    ZeroMemory(responseData, sizeof(responseData));

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FlushFileBuffers(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    if (hSensitiveWritePipe != NULL)
    {
        FlushFileBuffers(hSensitiveWritePipe);
        CloseHandle(hSensitiveWritePipe);
    }

    if (hSensitiveReadPipe != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(hSensitiveReadPipe);
    }

    if (hReadPipe != NULL) CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
    if (hWritePipe != NULL) CloseHandle(hWritePipe);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `SecureString` which is built into Microsoft .Net, information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It allows you to encrypt the data in memory, separated as individual character, and can instantly be disposed when you call `IDispose`, documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> - An instance of the System.String class is both immutable and, when no
>     longer needed, cannot be programmatically scheduled for garbage
>     collection; that is, the instance is read-only after it is created and
>     it is not possible to predict when the instance will be deleted from
>     computer memory. Consequently, if a String object contains sensitive
>     information such as a password, credit card number, or personal data,
>     there is a risk the information could be revealed after it is used
>     because your application cannot delete the data from computer memory.
> - **Important** This type implements the IDisposable
>     interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose
>     of it either directly or indirectly. To dispose of the type directly,
>     call its Dispose method in a try/catch block. To dispose of it
>     indirectly, use a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using
>     (in Visual Basic). For more information, see the “Using an Object that
>     Implements IDisposable” section in the IDisposable interface topic.
> - A SecureString object is similar to a String object in that it has a
>     text value. However, the value of a SecureString object is
>     automatically encrypted, can be modified until your application marks
>     it as read-only, and can be deleted from computer memory by either
>     your application or the .NET Framework garbage collector

The premise of `SecureString` is the following:

- No members to inspect, compare, and or convert.
- Implement `IDispose` when you've completed.
- Force the object into an encrypted `char []` in essence.

This design is to ensure that *no accidental or malicious exposure* can occur.

Comment: @hatchet I read that, but why is it not viable?  The whole point of `SecureString` is to take user input convert into an encrypted char [] and then dispose when your done with it.  In theory, it is correct if implemented correctly.

Comment: I see your point. You have to go out of your way to create a SecureString from a string (it's set up for char by char construction). So I don't see the basis for the OP dismissing it out of hand.

Comment: @hatchet The theory behind forcing a `string` into a `char []` is because the `string` is plain text.  By iterating through it one `char` at a time it should only exist at the single point in which it is introduced.  But all other instances will not be copied or moved and the single instance is simply that one input.  Nowhere else.

Comment: See above, but the SecureString class cannot be used for communicating to Vendors or File I/O.  I would prefer to stream to our 3rd party so as not to write to physical disk, but I do have that option.    In either case a Stream type object is needed and the GC tends to copy that all over memoryspace.

Comment: @BrianJenkins You may be better off using some form of encryption or hash then.  That way you can send it without a problem, then anytime the user places input it is handled.

You should be able to write your `char []` through a `MemoryStream` which would let you use the `SecureString`.  The real question would be, what your trying to do and to whom.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest either encrypting the sensitive data and never maintaining the plain text OR possible using a SecureString (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can init a SecureString with an empty string and then use `AppendChar` to build the string.  This avoids the need to keep plain text of the string.

Comment: @hatchet just because the OP stated that he already tried it, does not mean that using `SecureString` is incorrect.. especially when we can't see any code implementation or use.. I think what Richard is stating is valid in regards to the OP's Options

Comment: @hatchet, see amended answer.  Thanks MethodMan.

Comment: no problem.. it would be nice to see coded effort from the OP so we can understand the `What, and Why` in regards to why something is not working for them..

Comment: I am trying to work with our vendor about a mutual encryption process.   That is a possible solution if they can handle the decryption.  It still surprises me that C# does not have a better set of security objects for handling sensitive data such as credit cards, social security numbers, passwords etc besides SecureString - and the secure object must be loaded/unloaded in almost unsecure ways.  its a chicken/egg problem

Comment: The best way to handle passwords (etc) is too never use plain text.  Typically only the hash (SHA 256) of the passed around between services.

Comment: That should be a salted hash!